# PHPExcel Reading date from CSV

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have a CSV file containing date values.
Eg. 3/1/2015

But with my current code

```
$rowData[$i][0][6] = date('Y-m-d', PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($upper[0][6]));
```

it reads it as 2036-02-09.

I know PHPExcel is best used with xls and xlsx, but my boss tells me to use a csv file for a file upload event. How can i get the correct date?

Comment: Is this date actually a string in the CSV? Or is it an MS Excel timestamp (floating point) value?

Comment: why don't you try `fgetcsv` function to parse CSV file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to reformat it with strtotime like this:

```
$rowData[$i][0][6] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($upper[0][6])));
```

Or for PHP 5

```
$datetime = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($upper[0][6]); 
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y", $datetime);
// Format it as you want
echo $d->format("d.m.Y H:i:s");
```